# show that $ A_n \cup B_n \to A \cup B$ and $ A_n \cap B_n \to A \cap B$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

> Question:
>
> if $ A_n \to A $ and $ B_n \to B $, show that $ A_n \cup B_n \to A \cup B$ and $ A_n \cap B_n \to A \cap B$

My solution way is the following;

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} A_n = A $$ and $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} B_n = B $$

$(\liminf A_n)\cup (\liminf B_n) \subseteq \lim inf(A_n \cup B_n)\subseteq\lim sup(A_n \cup B_n)$

$= (\limsup A_n) \cup (\limsup B_n) $

I dont know whether this point correct or not.

$\liminf A_n = \limsup A_n =A$ and $\lim inf B_n = \lim sup B_n =B$

Also how can I prove the following statement

$ \liminf(A_n \cup B_n) \supset \liminf A_n \cup \liminf B_n$

All I can is that! I think that this is not exactly a proper solution. Thus, please show me a sound solution. thank you for helping.

Comment: Could you please define $A_n$ and $B_n$, are they sequences of sets?

Comment: yes they are sequences of sets. @MichaelBurr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first part looks good to me.  Recall that the elements of $\liminf A_n$ are in all but finitely many $A_n$'s.  The elements of $\limsup A_n$ are in infinitely many $A_n$'s.  Note that $\liminf A_n\subseteq \limsup A_n$ is always true.  When $\lim A_n=A$, then $\limsup A_n=\liminf A_n=A$.

If $x\in(\liminf A_n)\cup(\liminf B_n)$, then it is in all but finitely many of $A_n$ or $B_n$.  Therefore, it is in all but finitely many $A_n\cup B_n$ as these are bigger sets.  This gives your first line.

You are almost done with the proof at this point.  Suppose that $x\in\limsup (A_n\cup B_n)$.  This means that $x$ is in infinitely many $A_n\cup B_n$'s.  Now, since there are two sets here, $x$ is either in infinitely many $A_n$'s or infinitely many $B_n$'s.  Therefore, $x$ is in one of the $\limsup$'s.  Hence, $\limsup (A_n\cup B_n)\subseteq (\limsup A_n)\cup(\limsup B_n)$.

The other direction is similar.