# Prove that $A_n \cap B_n \rightarrow A \cap B$

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

If $A_n \rightarrow A$ and $B_n \rightarrow B$ are sequences of sets then is it true that $A_n \cap B_n \rightarrow A \cap B$? How to prove or provide a counterexample?

I had thought the following possible solution, but I am not convinced about it.

I tried to prove the following statements:

(i) $\liminf \left(A_n \cap B_n\right) = A \cap B$;

(ii) $\limsup \left(A_n \cap B_n\right) = A \cap B$;

thus, we can conclude that $\lim (A_n \cap B_n)$, i.e., $A_n \cap B_n \rightarrow A \cap B$

To prove these statements I use the following arguments:

(i) $\liminf \left(A_n \cap B_n\right) = \liminf A_n \cap \liminf B_n = A \cap B$;

(ii) $\limsup \left(A_n \cap B_n\right) \subset \limsup A_n \cap \limsup B_n = A \cap B$;

Therefore, $A_n \cap B_n \rightarrow A \cap B$.

Obs: A similar question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169580/show-that-a-n-cup-b-n-to-a-cup-b-and-a-n-cap-b-n-to-a-cap-b), but the response is not complete. Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: How do you define $A_n \to A$? Is it $\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k = A$?

Comment: You can certainly prove purely via the convergence of sets (by properly bounding them). But, it might be easier to note that $C_n\rightarrow C \Leftrightarrow 1_{C_n}\rightarrow 1_C$, where $1_{C}$ is the indicator of the set $C$ and the latter convergence is in the pointwise sense.

Comment: @md2perpe: the standard definition is $A=\lim_n A_n$ whenever $A=\bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k = \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$, i.e., the same as you wrote, but for the second equality that I wrote.

Comment: @AugustoSantos. So it's that $\liminf = \limsup$?

Comment: @md2perpe: yes. As a mnemonic you may replace '$\bigcup$' by '$\sup$' and '$\bigcap$' by '$\inf$'. In other words, $\bigcap_k \bigcup_{n\geq k} A_k = \inf_k \sup_{n\geq k} A_n = \limsup_n A_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By some fundamental union and intersection laws, and the de Morgan laws we have:
$$
\liminf (A_k \cap B_k)
= \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} (A_k \cap B_k)
= \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k \cap \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} B_k\right) 
= \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k \cap \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty} B_k  \\
= \liminf A_k \cap \liminf B_k
= A \cap B
.
$$

$$
\limsup(A_k \cap B_k) 
= \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} (A_k \cap B_k)
\subseteq \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k \cap \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} B_k \right)
= \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k \cap \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} B_k \\
= \limsup A_k \cap \limsup B_k
= A \cap B
.
$$

Thus,
$$
A \cap B
= \liminf (A_k \cap B_k)
\subseteq \limsup (A_k \cap B_k)
\subseteq A \cap B,
$$
which implies
$$
A \cap B 
= \liminf (A_k \cap B_k)
= \limsup (A_k \cap B_k), 
$$
i.e.
$$
A_k \cap B_k \to A \cap B.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 8):

The answer to your question comes trivially from the following lemma.

**Lemma.** $D_n\rightarrow D \Leftrightarrow 1_{D_n}\rightarrow 1_D$

**Proof.** Let us first show $\Rightarrow$.

Assume that $x\in D$. We need to show that $1_{D_n}(x)\rightarrow 1$. Note that $D=\bigcup_k \bigcap_{n\geq k} D_n$ and therefore, $x\in \bigcup_k \bigcap_{n\geq k} D_n$, i.e., $x\in D_n$ eventually. Therefore, $1_{D_n}(x)=1$ eventually and $1_{D_n}(x)\rightarrow 1$ holds.

Now, assume $x\notin D$. We need to show that $1_{D_n}(x)\rightarrow 0$. Note that $D_n^{c}\rightarrow D^{c}$, where $D^c$ is the complement of $D$. From the previous paragraph we conclude that $1_{D_n^c}(x)\rightarrow 1$ and thus, $1_{D_n}(x)\rightarrow 0$.

We now show $\Leftarrow$.

Let $x\in D$. We have that $1_{D_n}(x)\rightarrow 1$. In particular, $x\in D_n$ eventually. In other words, $D\subseteq \bigcup_{k} \bigcap_{n\geq k} D_n$. Now, we will show that $\bigcap_{k} \bigcup_{n\geq k} D_n\subseteq D$. Consider $x\in D_n$ infinitely often. Then, if $x\notin D$ we would have $1_{D_n}(x)=1$ infinitely often while $1_{D}(x)=0$ which contradicts the fact that $1_{D_n}(x)\rightarrow 1_D(x)$ for all $x$. We then conclude that $x\in D$ or in other words,

$\limsup_n D_n:=\bigcap_{k} \bigcup_{n\geq k} D_n\subseteq D \subseteq \bigcup_{k} \bigcap_{n\geq k} D_n=:\liminf_n D_n$.

This implies $D=\liminf_n D_n=\limsup_n D_n$, i.e., $D_n\rightarrow D$.