# How do we prove the given definitions of $\liminf A_{n}$ and $\limsup A_{n}$ are equivalent?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, stochastic-processes, limsup-and-liminf

I have to prove two similar identities involving the limit superior/inferior of a sequence of events in the event space but I'm not sure how to proceed. Here are the identities:
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty }A_n &= \bigg\{ \omega \in \Omega: \big|\{n\in \mathbb{N}{:\omega \in A_n } \}\big| =\infty\bigg\} \\ \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty }A_n &= \bigg\{ \omega \in \Omega: \big|\{n\in \mathbb{N}{:\omega \notin A_n } \}\big| <\infty\bigg\}.
\end{align*}

I know the relevant definitions as:
$$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty }A_n =\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k,\qquad \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty }A_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k $$
I have read that this identity basically states that the limit superior describes the event that infinitely many $A_i$'s occur and the limit inferior describes the event that all but a finite number of $A_i$'s occur but I haven't been able to construct something meaningful.

Comment: Work through the definitions step by step and prove each subset relation separately. Taking the lim sup for example: assuming $x\in \limsup A_n$, which means that $x\in\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty A_k$ for every $k$, you need to prove that $\#\{n\in\Bbb N\colon x\in A_n\} = \infty$. (Try a proof by contradiction.) Then you need to prove the converse.

Comment: @Alp: [this might be useful](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3291276/prove-that-a-n-cap-b-n-rightarrow-a-cap-b/3291452#3291452)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Another useful (and equivalent) way to rephrase the proposed definitions is given by:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle\liminf_{n\to\infty}A_{n} = \left\{\omega\in\Omega \mid \liminf_{n\to\infty}1_{A_{n}}(\omega) = 1\right\}\\\\
\displaystyle\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_{n} = \left\{\omega\in\Omega \mid \limsup_{n\to\infty}1_{A_{n}}(\omega) = 1\right\}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

where $1_{A_{n}}$ is the indicator function of the set $A_{n}$.

Can you take it from here?